# Accessing the inner array of an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, associative-array

I have created a very simple associative array of ids from a MySQL database.

Contents of the array look somewhat like this:

```
[0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(3) } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(4) } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(15) } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(17) } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(18) } 
[6]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(3) } etc.
```

However, for the purposes that I am using the array, I need to access the ID integers, so that they can be used to flag rows in the parent table.  However, the scripts that I have created do not seem to use the *["id"]=> int(2)* and therefore the code fails.

The code that I have as follows:

MySQL code:

```
  public function unused()
    {
        $query = "select person.id from person, thing, person_thing
WHERE flag = 1 AND person.id = person_thing.person_id AND person_thing.thing_id = thing.id and thing.name != 'used'
AND person.name NOT IN (select person.name from person, thing, person_thing WHERE person.id = person_thing.person_id
AND person_thing.thing_id = thing.id and thing.name = 'used')";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array());
        return 
        $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Function code:

```
{
        $things = $thing->unused();
        $smarty->assign('thing_used', $things);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($things); $i++) {
            $gameView->iterateThings($things[$i]);
        }
```

Iterate method code

```
Public function iterateThings($id)
    {
        $changeFlag = "UPDATE thingview SET flag = false WHERE  id= :id";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($changeFlag);
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));

    }
```

I have a view called set up which has boolean flags all set to true.  I'm trying to use this code change the flag settings on all the person.ids that are in the associative array $things.  Naively, I thought that this would be enough, but every time I run the code, the flags remain unchanged.  It appears that the contents of the array is: *array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) }* where what I need is *{ ["id"]=> int(2) }*.  I need the index gone and just the array.  I have googled this ad infinitum but have been unsuccessful.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that I have created a multidimensional array...  That was throwing me.  I believe at this point, more research is required on multidimensional arrays and should I need further help, I will rephrase the question.